# Find identical concatenated records within table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with email,gruppe as fields based on this information I would like to find all users with identical memberships (same gruppe) so I can group them into positions in the positions table. gruppe is a active directory group name which is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblsource] (
    [Id]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [email]  VARCHAR (150) NULL,
    [gruppe] VARCHAR (150) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblpositions] (
    [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [email]       VARCHAR (150) NULL,
    [position] VARCHAR (150) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I actually would like to write a hash or something similiar into position (it has to be identical if all the gruppe are identical).
This would allow me to easily identify all the persons which do have the same gruppe.
Any idea is appreciated (also different approaches) considering the fact I have to load the data from a spreadsheet.

tblsource (sample data):

```
user1@company.com,security-group1  
user1@company.com,security-group89  
user84@company.com,security-group89  
user3@company.com,security-group986  
user84@company.com,security-group1
```

so user1 and user84 have identical memberships and share therefore a position

Comment: Neither of these tables have a column called `membership`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding identical users with the same membership, you can try the following code.

```
;WITH cte_membership(email,membership)
AS
(
    SELECT  u.email,
        STUFF(
            (
                SELECT N','+m.[group]                   
                FROM dbo.tblsource m
                WHERE m.email=u.email
                ORDER BY m.[group]
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,'') AS membership
    FROM dbo.tblsource u
    GROUP BY u.[email]
),
cte_m(membership)
AS
(
    SELECT m.membership
    FROM cte_membership m
    GROUP BY m.membership
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
SELECT a.membership, b.email
FROM cte_m a
INNER JOIN cte_membership b
ON a.membership=b.membership;
```

Comment: That's the error message i get : Column 'cte_membership.email' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I renamed group to gruppe which reflects the database field name.

Comment: I updated the query. You can change it based on your table structure